# React: Pass a JSX component to parent

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using a Drawer component from a 3rd party library (antd). It accepts props such as title or footer that can be JSX elements.

How can I dynamically define the title in the child component and pass it up to the parent where the Drawer sits? useState does not seem the right choice because useState should not contain JSX elements.

```
const Inner = () => {

  const drawerTitle = <div>This should be the <strong>drawer title</strong></div>

  return (
      <div>I am the body of the drawer</div>
    )
  }

const PageDrawer = () => {

   return (
      <Drawer
         title={???}
         open={true}
      >
         <Inner />
      </Drawer>
   )
}
```

Comment: You can manage the state from a higher-order component, or maybe have a state management tool like redux.

Answer (score 0):

The part about dynamic changing of the title is missing so I assume the title will change depending on some prop

```
const Inner = (onDrawerTitleChange) => {

  const someProp = true; //change to false dynamically or whatever your logic requires

  const drawerTitleFactory = React.useCallback(someProp => {

    const drawerTitle = someProp ? (<div>This should be the <strong>drawer title</strong></div>) : (<div>other title</div>)

    onDrawerTitleChange(drawerTitle)  

  }, [onDrawerTitleChange, someProp]);

 
  return (
      <div>I am the body of the drawer</div>
    )
  }


const PageDrawer = () => {

   const [drawerTitle, setDrawerTitle] = React.useState(null);

   return (
      <Drawer
         title={drawerTitle}
         open={true}
      >
         <Inner onDrawerTitleChange={setDrawerTitle} />
      </Drawer>
   )
}
```

hard to say exactly what you need without knowing the requirements but the idea is to update the parent's state if the inner component changes. If your child doesn't have to be JSX but instead a prop that can be used as a factory it would be much easier.

The other options are:

- context
- state management tool like Redux, Flux, RQ etc.

Comment: thx for the elaborate answer but is it ok to have a whole JSX component in state? I learned that only simple stuff should go in there (boolean, a string, some simple object...)